# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison in python turtle

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote this recursive code which draws a hexagon spiral in turtle and then is supposed to draw a square spiral. But instead it sends me an error

> maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Yet it works when I execute both functions in separate files. In both cases the functions take as a parameter the number of spirals `n`.
Could someone explain to me why please?

```
def hexagon(n):
    if n>=1:
        forward(n)
        left(60)
    hexagon(n-1)

hexagon(100)
clearscreen()

def square(n):
    if n>=1:
        forward(n*5)
        right(90)
    square(n-1)

square(50)
```

Comment: It looks like infinite loop. You call recursively infinite times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an indentation error:

```
if n>=1:
    forward(n)
    left(60)
hexagon(n-1)
```

Which should be:

```
if n>=1:
    forward(n)
    left(60)
    hexagon(n-1)
```

And similarly in the `square()` function.  The complete code:

```
from turtle import *

def hexagon(n):
    if n >= 1:
        forward(n)
        left(60)
        hexagon(n-1)

def square(n):
    if n >= 1:
        forward(n*5)
        right(90)
        square(n-1)

hexagon(100)
clearscreen()
square(50)

done()
```